# Simplest way(s) to make a Julia package available to others

Tags: module, julia

Julia has a packaging system based on Git repositories with specific directories (package skeleton obtained with `Pkg.new("MyPackage")`), and a METADATA file that list packages and the git servers they can be found on.

`Pkg.init()` initializes a local Julia installation with the default list of package, but what are the exact steps to write in one's package documentation in order to let prospective users try it out with `Pkg.add("MyPackage"); require("MyPackage")` ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Any package source code can be manually placed in `.julia/MyPackage`. This can be done by unzipping a file, or checking out the package source from its repository manually. Once that is done, `require("MyPackge")` will work, just as with any official packages.

If you want to get users to try out Pkg.add("MyPackage"), you will need to provide them with your own METADATA repository. Clone the official repository, add your own package as usual. Then and ask users to initialise their julia package installation with `Pkg.init("url to metdata git repository")`. Once that is done, `Pkg.add("MyPackage")` will install the package from its own private git repository.

Comment: Thanks. We are getting there ;-). How would this work when several people propose to distribute packages this way (that is several people fork the official METADATA to add their own package) ?

Comment: I don't think there is much consideration for several people forking METADATA for distributing their own packages. The method I described above is really for temporarily testing an initial development of a package. Once you are ready to distribute a package to a wider userbase, you should add the package to the official METADATA. It takes a simple github pull request, and the requirements are not onerous at all (Only that the name be unique and reasonable). The actual package source continues to be under your own git. Any reason why you dont want to add a package to the official metadata?

Comment: There are various situations where an easy switching between collections of repositories, or a hierarchy of collections of repositories to look for a package, is desirable. One situation is people behind a corporate iron curtain sharing internal packages, while wanting to also fetch public ones. Otherwise I do not have a specific reason to not submit a pull request for my package. I will do it shortly, thanks for the answer(s).

Comment: Yes, you're right, I would expect that a company with an strong firewall would maintain their own METADATA repository, in the same way that, for example, they maintain their own maven or apt repositories. For more complex or controlled cases actually, the entire .julia directory is a git repository, that can be pushed and shared. But, you're right, there is currently no easy way to do a heirarchical metadata fetches. Maybe some deep git magic might help?

Comment: I just wanted to add that since this question was asked and answered a year ago, the package subsystem has undergone a major rewrite. Many of the issues discussed here are now much easier. For the details, see the official docs at http://docs.julialang.org/en/latest/manual/packages/

Answer (score 1):

For my own packages, I've been using the following boilerplate:

> The FILL_ME_IN package is available through the Julia package system. If you’ve never used the package system before, you’ll need to run the following:
>
> `require("pkg")`
>
> `Pkg.init()`
>
> `Pkg.add("FILL_ME_IN")`
>
> If you have an existing library of packages, you can pull the FILL_ME_IN package into your library using similar commands:
>
> `require("pkg")`
>
> `Pkg.add("FILL_ME_IN")`

Comment: Thanks. I am assuming that FILL_ME_IN refers to what is called "MyPackage" in the question, and supposes that this package is listed in the default METADATA shipped with "pkg". My question is "how do I make one's own package easily available to others ?", not "how do I pull a package listed in the official METADATA ?".